# Получить данные из JSON через JQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Как вывести данные из json через ajax jquery? Заранее благодарен за любую помощь.

```
<button class="add_new">Создать новый</button>
<div class="">
    <p>Фильтр</p>
    <input type="search" placeholder="Поиск">
    <div class="example">Здесь будут выведены JSON-данные</div>
    <div class="example">Здесь будут выведены JSON-данные</div>
    <div class="example">Здесь будут выведены JSON-данные</div>
    <div class="example">Здесь будут выведены JSON-данные</div>
</div>

{
"resp": {
    "direct": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "значение 1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "значение 2"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "значение 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

```
$.getJSON('data/direct.json', function(xhr){
  var items = [];

  $.each(xhr, function(key, val){
    items.push('id="' + key + '">' + 'name' + '');
  });

  $('<ul/>', {
    'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('body');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// api для примера
const API = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

// точка входа
const $app = $('#app');

// создаем нужные элементы
const $ul = $('<ul class="list" />');
const $li = $('<li class="list-item" />');

$.getJSON(API, function(response) {
  // метод [].map() - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
  const items = response.map(function(user) {
    // jQuery.fn.clone()
    const item = $li.clone();

    item.text(user.name);

    return item;
  });
  
  $ul.append(items);
  $app.append($ul);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Да спасибо помогло, мне пришлось править JSON, что в принципе нельзя делать. Как правильно путь прописать к данным и что бы значение "name" отправлял в отдельный блок. Сейчас он создает список и весь массив отправляет в список